# Office reference to cell specified in another cell

Tags: excel

Is it possible to make something like reference to column or table defined in some row?

For example: in a cell A1 I specified which column I want to choose maybe B, and in A2 I specified which row I want to choose maybe 2.
So

```
`A1 = B, A2 = 2, B2 = 99`
```

Now I want to connect my A1 and A2 cell to display B2 cell. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(A1,A2))
```

The "Concatenate" formula would make "B2" and the "Indirect" would give you the result of the cell "B2".

[Info Indirect](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) and  [Info Concatenate](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d).

Comment: THANK YOU ALOT, YOU SAVED ME A LOT OF TIME

Comment: @Micchaleq - welcome. You may consider accepting the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers